# Why is changing WPF DataGrid ItemsSource so extremely slow in .NET 4.6?

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

For example try this trivial WPF window:

```
<Window x:Class="MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">

    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="30" />
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <TextBox Grid.Row="0" Text="{Binding Path=Filter, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />

        <DataGrid Grid.Row="1" ItemsSource="{Binding FilteredList}">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding}" />
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>

    </Grid>
</Window>
```

with this code behind:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows;

public partial class MainWindow : Window, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    List<string> items = new List<string>();
    string filter = string.Empty;

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = this;
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) items.Add(i.ToString());
    }

    public IEnumerable<string> FilteredList
    {
        get { return this.items.Where(item => item.Contains(filter)).ToArray(); }
    }

    public string Filter
    {
        get { return filter; }
        set
        {
            if (filter != value)
            {
                filter = value;
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("FilteredList"));
            }
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged = (s, e) => { };
}
```

There are only one hundred strings in the grid. The textbox allows filtering the strings.

But writing for example `123` into the filter and then deleting it again freezes the application for multiple seconds. Why is this not instant?

Edit: In .NET 4.5 it is indeed instant, even with 10'000 items. Seems to be a regression in .NET 4.6?

Comment: Typing "123", then deleting the text raises the PropertyChanged event for `FilteredList` four times. Each time the property changes, the whole DataGrid content is re-created, because the entire `ItemsSource` collection is replaced.  Note also that `ToArray()` in the property getter is redundant.

Comment: @Clemens But why would this be a problem that requires multiple seconds?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`DataGrid.EnableColumnVirtualization` is False by default. Setting it to True helps.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you replace the entire collection every time.
You should use an CollectionViewSource as the source of your DataGrid. CollectionViewSource accept filters expression. So, you can create a CollectionViewSource based on your original IEnumerable and create a filter method based on your text box value. Then call the method Refresh of your CollectionViewSource

Comment: But why does this matter so much? Why does it take multiple seconds to bind a small collection?

Comment: In an algorithm, the order is importan O(n) in this case, but, the constant is important too. In your case every time you type a letter you calculate 100 strings and filter it. Then you print this strings in to the screen (100 more operations). For example, if your filter word is 123, it have 3 letters, it turns in to 3*2*100 = 600 operations. The CollectionViewSource anwer have the original source internally calculated, if you set a filter it remove or add elements from the screen. The constant go down

Comment: But 600 operations is nothing. The constant factor is ridiculously high.
It seems to be a regression in .NET 4.6 or something. In 4.5 it's much faster (instantaneous really) as expected even with 10'000 items in the list.